# Flattening nested JSON in R

Tags: r, json, flatten

Hi folks: I've searched stack overflow and the rest of the internet for an answer to this question, but none of the answers I can find seem to work for me.

I've got thousands of rows of json data with information about images from a camera trap study. I'm having lots of trouble unpacking the data.  I'm using `jsonlite::fromJSON` to no avail. Same for `as.tbl_json` from tidyjson.

My goal is to write some code that will give me a data frame with a column for each variable stored in the json format.  Can you help?

Here's a vector of data that I'm playing with, though I actually have the data as a single column in a larger `.csv` file .  First row is the column name.

```
annotations<-c(annotations,
"[{""task"":""T0"",""value"":[{""choice"":""NOTHINGHERE"",""answers"":{},""filters"":{}}]}]"
"[{""task"":""T0"",""value"":[{""choice"":""NOTHINGHERE"",""answers"":{},""filters"":{}}]}]"
"[{""task"":""T0"",""value"":[{""choice"":""DEERWHITETAILED"",""answers"":{""HOWMANY"":""1"",""YOUNGPRESENT"":""NO"",""ANTLERSPRESENT"":""NO"",""WHATBEHAVIORSDOYOUSEE"":[""ALERT""],""ESTIMATEOFSNOWDEPTHSEETUTORIAL"":""NOSNOWBAREGROUND"",""ISITACTIVELYRAININGORSNOWINGINTHEPICTURE"":""NO""},""filters"":{}}]}]"
"[{""task"":""T0"",""value"":[{""choice"":""NOTHINGHERE"",""answers"":{},""filters"":{}}]}]"
"[{""task"":""T0"",""value"":[{""choice"":""NOTHINGHERE"",""answers"":{},""filters"":{}}]}]"
"[{""task"":""T0"",""value"":[{""choice"":""NOTHINGHERE"",""answers"":{},""filters"":{}}]}]"
"[{""task"":""T0"",""value"":[{""choice"":""NOTHINGHERE"",""answers"":{},""filters"":{}}]}]"
"[{""task"":""T0"",""value"":[{""choice"":""NOTHINGHERE"",""answers"":{},""filters"":{}}]}]"
"[{""task"":""T0"",""value"":[{""choice"":""FISHER"",""answers"":{""HOWMANY"":""1"",""YOUNGPRESENT"":""NO"",""WHATBEHAVIORSDOYOUSEE"":[""WALKINGRUNNING"",""ALERT""],""ESTIMATEOFSNOWDEPTHSEETUTORIAL"":""1020CM"",""ISITACTIVELYRAININGORSNOWINGINTHEPICTURE"":""NO""},""filters"":{}}]}]"
"[{""task"":""T0"",""value"":[{""choice"":""NOTHINGHERE"",""answers"":{},""filters"":{}}]}]")
```

Here's what I get if I run dput(annotations):

```
structure(list(annotations = c("[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"NOTHINGHERE\",\"answers\":{},\"filters\":{}}]}]", 
"[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"NOTHINGHERE\",\"answers\":{},\"filters\":{}}]}]", 
"[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"DEERWHITETAILED\",\"answers\":{\"HOWMANY\":\"1\",\"YOUNGPRESENT\":\"NO\",\"ANTLERSPRESENT\":\"NO\",\"WHATBEHAVIORSDOYOUSEE\":[\"ALERT\"],\"ESTIMATEOFSNOWDEPTHSEETUTORIAL\":\"NOSNOWBAREGROUND\",\"ISITACTIVELYRAININGORSNOWINGINTHEPICTURE\":\"NO\"},\"filters\":{}}]}]", 
"[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"NOTHINGHERE\",\"answers\":{},\"filters\":{}}]}]", 
"[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"NOTHINGHERE\",\"answers\":{},\"filters\":{}}]}]", 
"[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"NOTHINGHERE\",\"answers\":{},\"filters\":{}}]}]", 
"[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"NOTHINGHERE\",\"answers\":{},\"filters\":{}}]}]", 
"[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"NOTHINGHERE\",\"answers\":{},\"filters\":{}}]}]", 
"[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"FISHER\",\"answers\":{\"HOWMANY\":\"1\",\"YOUNGPRESENT\":\"NO\",\"WHATBEHAVIORSDOYOUSEE\":[\"WALKINGRUNNING\",\"ALERT\"],\"ESTIMATEOFSNOWDEPTHSEETUTORIAL\":\"1020CM\",\"ISITACTIVELYRAININGORSNOWINGINTHEPICTURE\":\"NO\"},\"filters\":{}}]}]", 
"[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"NOTHINGHERE\",\"answers\":{},\"filters\":{}}]}]"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: This syntax doesn't make sense. Should there be a comma in `c(annotations
"[{""task""...`?

Comment: I'm glad you asked.  I forgot to put a comma after the `c(annotations, ...` but just fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean that `fromJSON` doesn't work? For instance, if I try `lapply(annotations$annotations,fromJSON)` I get something. Is it different from what you expect?

Comment: This works for me, too, for getting a list.  But I'm trying to get a flattened data frame. When I add `flatten = T` I also still get just a list.  I'm looking for an elegant way to extract all the elements of the list into a data frame with fairly little code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not completely clear to me exactly what output format you are looking for. There are lots of different ways you can do this. Further, the arrays in your data structure (which only have one object in them, each) complicate matters a bit because they *could* have more objects in them.

In any case, `tidyjson` doesn't require too much code thanks to `spread_all()`. You could also spread only particular values with `spread_values()`, or `enter_object(answers)` to just spread answers, etc. Hope it helps!

```r
library(tidyjson)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tidyjson'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
library(tibble)

annotations <- structure(list(annotations = c("[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"NOTHINGHERE\",\"answers\":{},\"filters\":{}}]}]", 
                                              "[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"NOTHINGHERE\",\"answers\":{},\"filters\":{}}]}]", 
                                              "[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"DEERWHITETAILED\",\"answers\":{\"HOWMANY\":\"1\",\"YOUNGPRESENT\":\"NO\",\"ANTLERSPRESENT\":\"NO\",\"WHATBEHAVIORSDOYOUSEE\":[\"ALERT\"],\"ESTIMATEOFSNOWDEPTHSEETUTORIAL\":\"NOSNOWBAREGROUND\",\"ISITACTIVELYRAININGORSNOWINGINTHEPICTURE\":\"NO\"},\"filters\":{}}]}]", 
                                              "[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"NOTHINGHERE\",\"answers\":{},\"filters\":{}}]}]", 
                                              "[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"NOTHINGHERE\",\"answers\":{},\"filters\":{}}]}]", 
                                              "[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"NOTHINGHERE\",\"answers\":{},\"filters\":{}}]}]", 
                                              "[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"NOTHINGHERE\",\"answers\":{},\"filters\":{}}]}]", 
                                              "[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"NOTHINGHERE\",\"answers\":{},\"filters\":{}}]}]", 
                                              "[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"FISHER\",\"answers\":{\"HOWMANY\":\"1\",\"YOUNGPRESENT\":\"NO\",\"WHATBEHAVIORSDOYOUSEE\":[\"WALKINGRUNNING\",\"ALERT\"],\"ESTIMATEOFSNOWDEPTHSEETUTORIAL\":\"1020CM\",\"ISITACTIVELYRAININGORSNOWINGINTHEPICTURE\":\"NO\"},\"filters\":{}}]}]", 
                                              "[{\"task\":\"T0\",\"value\":[{\"choice\":\"NOTHINGHERE\",\"answers\":{},\"filters\":{}}]}]"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

ant <- tibble(raw = annotations$annotations)

as.tbl_json(ant, json.column = "raw") %>%
  gather_array("object_id") %>% 
  spread_all() %>%
  enter_object("value") %>%
  gather_array("value_id") %>%
  spread_all() %>%
  as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 10 x 9
#>    object_id task  value_id choice answers.HOWMANY answers.YOUNGPR…
#>        <int> <chr>    <int> <chr>  <chr>           <chr>           
#>  1         1 T0           1 NOTHI… <NA>            <NA>            
#>  2         1 T0           1 NOTHI… <NA>            <NA>            
#>  3         1 T0           1 DEERW… 1               NO              
#>  4         1 T0           1 NOTHI… <NA>            <NA>            
#>  5         1 T0           1 NOTHI… <NA>            <NA>            
#>  6         1 T0           1 NOTHI… <NA>            <NA>            
#>  7         1 T0           1 NOTHI… <NA>            <NA>            
#>  8         1 T0           1 NOTHI… <NA>            <NA>            
#>  9         1 T0           1 FISHER 1               NO              
#> 10         1 T0           1 NOTHI… <NA>            <NA>            
#> # … with 3 more variables: answers.ANTLERSPRESENT <chr>,
#> #   answers.ESTIMATEOFSNOWDEPTHSEETUTORIAL <chr>,
#> #   answers.ISITACTIVELYRAININGORSNOWINGINTHEPICTURE <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks cole.  I don't have the reputation to do much other than thank you here.  This worked. I appreciate the help!

Comment: My pleasure! Very glad to hear it helped!